# IntentService JSON download and saving data

Tags: android, json, service, intentservice

In my main activity i am sending a HTTP GET request (with user GPS location and a range) to server by clicking on a button and get server response as JSON with a list of places around the position of the client and inside the range specified in the request.

I want to wait for this response to do some other stuff on this list. I am using a AsyncTask.

Since this task is the main purpose of the application and it can be repeated multiple times, to avoid the request for the list every time the user click on the button. I want to reuse the list.

To reuse the list the more possible number of times. I can ask the server a list with a bigger range. But the more the range is higher the more the response is slower.

So I think that I should ask this bigger list in background by using an IntentService, is it right?

How can I save the results of the IntentService without using a local DB(I don't need to refresh the UI)? (so that I can check if a bigger list exists, if it's valid (w.r.t. user current location) and use it) Is it possible to share this list in different activity (without passing with Intents)?

Comment: I don't understand your question properly. But if you want to save some kind of data so best available option is json and save it into preference it is  faster then DB...

Comment: You can access that saved json from different activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is piece of code**

```
String jsonData="your json data you wanna save";

SharedPreferences  sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//save your incoming json
    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit(); 
editor.putString("mydata",jsonData); editor.commit();

//Access your saved json from anywhere or from other activities
  String myDataBack=sharedpreferences.getString("mydata","");

//compare your data
```

Comment: Since the JSON is pretty long, I'm trying to saving it in the application cache as a File.

Comment: The real maximum ~500KB (rarely reached) but it won't exceed the maximum number of characters that can have a string in Java.

Can i directly store the string  in SharedPreferences from the IntentService (that runs in another thread.. but Service inherits Context) or should i receive  the json in my application first?

Comment: You can also use 'id' for each response so there is no need to compare whole data which is more convenient....